# How to determine a child view's parent when click event fires?

Tags: android, button, onclick

I am using the template layout which I import into different `LinearLayouts`. The template has a button in it.

When a user presses the button, I need to know in which `LinearLayout` the click event has occurred. Is this possible?

I am getting problem firing parent's event as when you press the child element, the parent's event will not fire at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can get parent of any view using method:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getParent%28%29

Comment: Thanks. But I am surprised it does not have method `getId()` (I mean `v.getParent().NO-GETID-METHOD`). How should I identify the parent?

Comment: getParent() returns View, from that View you can get view id, so to get id int id=view.getParent().getId();

Comment: I cannot. In the `onClick`, method `getParent` returns `ViewParent` object, not `View`. Event casting `(View)(v.getParent()).NO-GETID` does not show getId() method. Please try if you do not believe. So weird!

Comment: You seem to be misplacing the brackets, try: `((View)v.getParent()).getId()`.

Comment: do like: View view=(View)v.getParent(); int id=view.getId();

Comment: @jitendrasharma Thanks. The casting was an issue. After it, I got `getId()`.